# Plotting data from Excel file in python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, matplotlib, openpyxl

How to plot data which is already in an excel file?
I would like to plot data using matplotlib by extracting data from excel file.
How to assign data in Excel file to x,y axis when declaring in matplotlib?

Comment: Please provide more info so that I can help more. for example what is your data (bring for example the first 5 records) and what kind of plot you want to draw?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the excel data and depending on the type of data and the plot type you can use different functions:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excelfile.xls')
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Consider that it is the simplest script and you can set a lot of other parameters to modify plot and data.